# Post Per Page Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, jquery-post

PHP noob here trying to increase post per page here to 99

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
```

but I dont want to add `<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=99'); ?>` above the if statement.

Comment: You can easily do that via WordPress admin.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without using any php:

- Go to http://example.com/wp-admin/options-reading.php **OR**
- From the dashboard go to the "Settings" option then the "Reading" option in that.
- The second heading on that page is "Blog pages show at most", change that to 99
- You should now see 99 posts per page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are correct not to use `query_posts`. You should never ever use `query_posts`, never. If you ever need a custom query, you should use `WP_Query` or `get_posts`

If you need to change anything on the home page (not front page) or any type of archive page (this excludes page.php type templates), use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query, this is the correct and only way to change the main query. Use conditional tags to target specific pages

To change the posts per page for only the home page, you can do something like this

```
function custom_ppp($query) {

    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '99' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_ppp' );
```